# Sequestially numbering json data in pandas column

Tags: python

I have data where a column has string "1.png", "2.png", "3.png". how would i chnage this to "11.png", "12.png, "13.png"

df = A: [1,2,3,4]

to

df = A: [11,12,13,14]

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4]})

df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: "1" + str(x))

    A
0  11
1  12
2  13
3  14
```